# How to reuse ArrayDescriptor?

Tags: java, arrays, oracle, database-connection

I tried the code below:

```
public class Abc {

    private ArrayDescriptor arrayDesc;

    void init() {
       connection = //create connection
        arrayDesc = ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor("DBTYPE",connection);
    }

    void m1() {
        conn1 = //create connection
        ARRAY array_to_pass1 = new ARRAY( arrayDesc , conn1, idsArray1 ); 
    }

    void m2() {
        conn2 = //create connection
        ARRAY array_to_pass2 = new ARRAY( arrayDesc , conn2, idsArray2 ); 
    }

}
```

This code is giving the error below:

> table.java.sql.SQLException: Missing descriptor
>   at oracle.sql.DatumWithConnection.assertNotNull(DatumWithConnection.java:103)

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

[ArrayDescriptor](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/sql/ArrayDescriptor.html) is deprecated. Assuming your `connection` objects are of type [OracleConnection](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createOracleArray_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_), try using [createOracleArray](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JAJDB/oracle/jdbc/OracleConnection.html#createOracleArray_java_lang_String__java_lang_Object_) instead - something like this:

```
public class Abc {
    void init() {
        connection = //create connection
    }

    void m1() {
        conn1 = //create connection
        array array_to_pass1 = conn1.createOracleArray(arrayDesc, idsArray1); 
    }

    void m2() {
        conn2 = //create connection
        array array_to_pass2 = conn2.createOracleArray(arrayDesc, idsArray2); 
    }
}
```

Note: Using this method, the arrays will be of type **`java.sql.Array`** rather than `oracle.sql.ARRAY`.

Answer (score 0):

`new ARRAY` must be called with an ArrayDescriptor that uses the same connection. So what you're trying to do won't work. Note that each connection has a cache of descriptors so creating the descriptor will happen just once per connection.